# Unable to click download button with web scraper

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

for whatever reason mechanize is unable to click this export button to automate downloading a public government csv file, i'm trying to automate downloading a fishing report, does anyone have any ideas on how to get it to work?

```rb
agent = Mechanize.new
url = 'https://nrm.dfg.ca.gov/FishPlants/'

log :debug, "reading HTML from #{url}"
page = agent.get(url)

log :debug, 'loaded page'
form = page.search('#aspnetForm').first
button = page.search('.application_button').first

log :debug, 'clicking Export button'
response = agent.submit(form, button)
```

i get a stack trace with the following error

```
...
    form.add_button_to_query(button) if button
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/aronlilland/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/mechanize-2.8.5/lib/mechanize.rb:581:in `submit'
/Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/fishing-report/tasks/download/fishing_report.rake:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => download:fishing_report
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

the form is confirmed returns successfully, but the button is an input field

the page seems relatively straight forward, so dont know why i'm unable to scrape it - and its also public data

```html
<form method="post" action="./" id="aspnetForm">
  <!-- .... -->
  <input
    type="submit"
    name="ctl00$cphContentMiddle$btnExport"
    value="Export"
    id="ctl00_cphContentMiddle_btnExport"
    class="application_button"
  >
  <!-- .... -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `agent.submit` got the wrong type for `form`

The issue here could be seen if you had included the beginning of the stack trace:

```
.../ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/mechanize-2.8.5/lib/mechanize.rb:581:in `submit': undefined method `add_button_to_query' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1ea14 name="form" attributes=
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0xbd38 name="method" value="post">, ...
```

Mechanize expects the submit to act on a `Mechanize::Form` instance, but instead got an instance of `Nokogiri::XML::Element`, as you can see by adding this to your code:

```ruby
form.class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

If you check the docs for the [`Mechanize::Form`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/2.8.5/Mechanize/Form) class, you can see the example they give to get you the form object is this:

```ruby
form = page.forms.first # => Mechanize::Form
```

as opposed to what you used:

```ruby
form = page.search('#aspnetForm').first
```

The call to `search` here is [delegated to Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/v2.8.5/lib/mechanize/page.rb#L239), and therefore doesn't return the object type you need, but rather a `Nokogiri` element.

## `button` also has the wrong type

By the way the same applies to this line:

```ruby
button = page.search('.application_button').first
```

If you fix the type of `form`, you'll get into a similar issue with `button` not being the expected type. Again, there's an [example in the docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/2.8.5/Mechanize#submit-instance_method) showing how a button is found:

```ruby
agent.submit(page.forms.first, page.forms.first.buttons.first)
```

You'll need to figure out how to find the specific button you need though, I haven't worked with Mechanize before, so I can't offer a suggestion here. Presumably there's a way to convert the button you find through `search` to a [`Mechanize::Form::Button`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mechanize/2.8.5/Mechanize/Form/Button) instance.

Comment: nailed it, thanks for the detailed answer, its evident you ran the code yourself! I was able to get my download file working thanks to you!